# Readind data from Excel 2016 through C# windows application

Tags: c#, excel

I'm working on a application where I want to read from excel 2016 through C# windows application. The code I've written (see below for code) works fine when the excel file is open. But when I run the code when the excel file is not open, it throws an OleDbexception "External table is not in the expected format."

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System;

namespace ExcelRead
{
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='D:\Practice.xlsx';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'");
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [sheet1$];", con);
        OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dr.GetString(0) + "\t" + dr.GetString(1) + "\t" + dr.GetString(2));
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code, as you are not maintaining connection which can generate as instance of the excel sheet that is why you are getting error.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            // Create Connection to Excel Workbook
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='D:\Practice.xlsx';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'"))
            {
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select * FROM [Sheet1$]", connection);
                connection.Open();
                // Create DbDataReader to Data Worksheet
                using (OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(dr.GetString(0) + "\t" + dr.GetString(1) + "\t" + dr.GetString(2));
                }
            }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: It still throwing the same exception.

Comment: @Ashis, Please use " IMEX=1" in connection string.